# Square connect API - iOS SDK offline mode error

Tags: square-connect

I am trying to test offline payment mode. But when I tried to make payment from my app offline, I got below error in Register App

[image]

Also, offline mode is ON from settings

[image]

So, am I missing something to configure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have internet connection at least in the beginning so that we can validate your application against what you have registered in the developer portal. After that you can process in offline mode.

Comment: internet connection at least in the beginning - meaning ? each time when my app opens Register app or 1st time when my app opens Register ? Because I already made more than 20 online transactions.

Comment: Just the first time that you process a transaction with your app. Were those transactions made with your app or the Square register app?

Comment: Those were by Register app. My app passed amount to Register app and Register made the transactions

Comment: Any help ? did I misunderstood any thing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it what was the issue.

For the very first time Square Register app requires the internet to validate our app. After that no need to kill Square Register app so it will be in background. So next time Square Register app wont need internet connection to validate our app.

If Square Register app is killed and open again then it will require the internet.